# Xamarin.Forms Nullpointer when Converter Ressource called

Tags: xamarin.forms

I created a Converter:

```
namespace MoneyFox.Business.Converter
{
    public class InverseBoolConverter: IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return !(bool) value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return !(bool)value;
        }
    }
}
```

And I added a namespace to my page:

```
xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:MoneyFox.Business"

<ContentView.Resources>
    <converter:InverseBoolConverter x:Key="inverter" />
</ContentView.Resources>

<Button Text="{Binding LoginButtonLabel}" IsVisible="{Binding IsLoggedIn, Converter={StaticResource inverter}}" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" />
```

When I now navigate to the page, it crashes with a NullPointerException. As soon as I remove the converter it works again.

```
   'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
   at MoneyFox.Business.Views.BackupPage.InitializeComponent()
   at MoneyFox.Business.Views.BackupPage..ctor()
```

I assumed that my namespace declaration is wrong, but from what I saw here it should be correct: 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/

Also there is no error on compiling that the inverter isn't found in the namespace (which appears when I deliberatly change the namespace to a wrong one).

Can someone give me a hint on what that might be?

Comment: why are trying to apply a converter to a Command binding?

Comment: @Jason I'm sorry, I inserted it wrong after trying around. I corrected it in my initial post. thanks for point out :)

Comment: have you tried debugging the converter code?  Checking for a null value?

Comment: yeah, but it isn't called at all. Also I can remove the Converter from the IsVisible Tag and it still crashes as long as the Ressource definition is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `<ResourceDictionary>` element:

```
xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:MoneyFox.Business"

<ContentView.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <converter:InverseBoolConverter x:Key="inverter" />
  </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentView.Resources>

<Button Text="{Binding LoginButtonLabel}" IsVisible="{Binding IsLoggedIn, Converter={StaticResource inverter}}" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" />
```